# Login page that redirects

Tags: php, authentication

Can anyone help me get this right?
I need a simple login page and have 2 files. After checking the username and password it should redirect to a index1.php page and it is here my head spins. I can't get it right. Can anyone please see what I should put in my code?

login.function.php

```
    ?php

     session_start(); 


     function login($username, $password) 
     { 
         //Correct u and pw
         $correct_user = "Admin"; 
         $correct_pass = "test"; 

         //Step 1 
         if ( !empty($username) && !empty($password) ) 
         { 

          //Step 2 
         if ( $username == $correct_user  
          && $password == $correct_pass ) 
         { 

          //Step3 
          $_SESSION['user_login'] = TRUE; 
          } 

          //If u or pw is false 
         else 
          { 
           return "bla bla bla..."; 
        } 
    } 

     //If user or pw is empty 
     { 
        return "You have to give u and pw."; 
    } 

   } 


     /********************************************* 
      * to log out
     *********************************************/ 
    function logout() 
    { 
    $_SESSION['user_login'] = FALSE; 
    session_destroy(); 
    } 

    /********************************************************** 

     *********************************************************/ 
    function is_logon() 
    { 
         if ( isset($_SESSION['user_login'])  
         && $_SESSION['user_login'] == TRUE ) 
     { 
         return TRUE; 
    } 
      else 
     { 
         return FALSE; 
     } 
    } 

    ?>
```

And here is the index.php file that should after sucessfull login redirect to the index1.php file

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
         <td align="center"><form action="" method="post">
       User:<br>
       <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="login_form" value="1">
        <input type="submit" value="Logga in">
    </form></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `action=""` posts the form back to the same page, there is no code on that page which invokes them functions.

Comment: Thank you but could you please show me in my code? I need to get to the index1.php page after sucessful login

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="">` should be `<form action="index1.php">` because this will send the user to index1.php with the POST request.

Comment: Thank you but this does not check the loginstatus

Answer (score -1):

The form method and action should be like this

`<form method="post" action="login.function.php">`

And in step 3 after setting **user_login** session to true you should redirect user to your **index1.php** file with

`header('Location: http://www.example.com/index1.php');`

Then you should check **user_login** session at the beginning of **index1.php** file if it's set to false redirect back user to the login page.

Comment: @MagicWoman If you have copied the code above that I mentioned check if any thing is extra, in the error it says that unexpected `'**'`. If everything seems okay please send a screenshot for me.

Comment: Ok, I saw the problem but now I am just getting to the login.function.php when I type any wrong ocr right pw.
What should the check_login in index1.php look like and where do I put it?.

Comment: In login.function.php after setting the session you should redirect user to the index1.php page, and at the begginnig of index1.php you should check that `if($_SESSION['user_login'] == False) header('Location: http://www.example.com/login.php');`